# I can't find www directory in EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11 folder. Did I install it wrong?

Tags: installation, easyphp

I followed install instruction of EasyPHP for Windows but I could not find the EasyPHP 1-7 mentioned from the book. I choose the EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11 download package instead. The book supposes that there is a www folder in EasyPHP1-7 so for my real installion with EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11, where can I find Apache Document Root folder? I already searched for www folder but I could not find one.

Comment: is there a htdocs folder?

Comment: I've already found the location of the root folder, it's said in the httpd.conf file. Thanks Chilion

Answer (score 0):

Search for the htdocs folder. Otherwise, It will be mentioned in the httpd.conf file! :-)